# Textfield in hover is not working properly in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm having trouble with developing in IE, I've made a great header, but now I was checking everything in Internet Explorer and I've found a few bugs,

One is the following, I've never had something like this, that's why I'm really obsessed with this problem. I'm not even sure if anyone knows how to fix this, accept the challenge!

I know placeholder DOESNT work in IE, but that's obviously not the problem. If you are in the hover, and you're going over the text field, the box disappears, and you need to go over it again.

Here some code:

```
<ul>
    <div class="transparant">
        <div class="dropbox">
            <div class="login">
                <div class="textfield">
                     <form method="post">
                       <input id="textfield_post" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Gebruikersnaam" class="matrix"/>    
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="pass">
                <div class="textfield">
                    <input id="textfield_post" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Wachtwoord" class="matrix"/>   
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="loginbutton">   
                <input type="submit" class="btn" value= "Login" type="button" id="login_button"></form>
            </div>

            <div class="forgotpass">
                <a href="#" onclick="NewPassword()">Forgot password?</A>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</ul>
```

I think it is because of the z-index. Also, I don't want to use jquery or anything, I just want to fix the problem using right HTML & CSS.

I'm asking you if anyone is familiar with this problem,

The website:  (it is only at IE 7&8)

Thanks for reading;)

Comment: provide the css file as well. So it will be easier to check the problem.

Comment: Not sure if it will help but your FORM tag only surrounds the first input when it should surround all form fields including the button.

Comment: //misreaded you.. I know that, but thats not the problem atm. Billy, indeed ive noticed if i get away the value, it works, but then there is no "placeholder" thingy for IE.

Comment: Hey Bobby, the css is in the demo

Comment: FYI: You have an extra closing DIV tag than is need in this code same and you've not closed your form element.

Comment: It looks like the demo website has been modified (in good taste, I might add :) ). Could you post the relevant CSS to troubleshoot for IE7/8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you empty the textboxes the problem is solved. I don't know if you accept that work around but hey, it works :)

Answer (score 3):

I guess you used `:hover` CSS or `mouseover()` JQuery to make the box appears. I suggest to use `mouseentered()` check the following link:

http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/different-between-mouseover-and-mouseenter-in-jquery/

and to be sure make the ul `overflow:hidden`

Comment: To be honest, I think this is an great idea, ill try to use it!|Also not sure if this will work, but who's not trying, who's not reaching

Answer (score 1):

IE currently Does not  support `Placeholder`.i recommend you to  move with `JQuery`. here is the sample  code

```
<p><script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        if (!$.support.placeholder) {
            var active = document.activeElement;
            $(':text').focus(function () {
                if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder')) {
                    $(this).val('').removeClass('hasPlaceholder');
                }
            }).blur(function () {
                if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && ($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder'))) {
                    $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder')).addClass('hasPlaceholder');
                }
            });
            $(':text').blur();
            $(active).focus();
        }
    });
</script>
</p>
```

Hope it helps